# Will using 2x2GB ram use more power than 1x4GB ram?

Tags: memory, power-supply

I've recently upgraded my ASUS K45VD laptop from 2GB memory to 4GB memory by adding a 2GB stick. 
Then I got problems 2 times. The first time, asus's service said that the mainboard is down and they got me a another one. Everything was just fine until yesterday, it was down again while I was playing a heavy game (NFS 2012), it just went down and i can't even charge my laptop.

So at first, I thought i could be a problem with mixing the 2 rams of different model. But because I can't charge the laptop, it can be a problem with the power supply.

what is the difference between only 1 RAM (4GB) and using 2 RAM(2B). Or my power supply just cannot supply enough power for 4GB of memory?

Answer (score 5):

It does cost more power to run 2 RAM modules than 1 but the difference is so small that your power supply should keep up. Actually, having 2 modules usually speeds your computer up as most modern systems are able to use a dual-channel system for memory.

These problems usually occur when mixing two different types of RAM, I recommend you never do this.

Comment: But I did mix them. Should I just buy another 4gb ram or buy another 2gb ram that is exactly the same as one of my old ram? I'm scared of using 2 ram after these time.

Comment: I recommend you buy two of the same 2GB modules. These are often sold in a kit.